# Plotting contour in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

I have an np array of shape (15,2)
When I meshgrid first and second dimension of this array and write a function of this array, and then plot using contour, the output is blank. I don't understand what's wrong. Please guide me.

The code is:

```
M=[[12.647,4.2439],[13.744,8.9295],[13.93,9.191 ],[16.223,12.452 ],
   [16.475 , 12.784 ],
   [16.535 , 12.813 ],
   [16.774 , 13.377 ],
   [16.949 , 13.465 ],
   [17.295 , 13.494 ],
   [17.329 , 13.613 ],
   [18.183 , 14.683 ],
   [19.055 , 14.871 ],
   [19.098 , 15.487 ],
   [21.798 , 16.23  ],
   [22.241 , 16.411 ]]
x1,y1=np.meshgrid(M[:,0],M[:,1])
F=np.sqrt(x1**2 + y1**2)
plt.contour(x1,y1,F)
```

Here M is a np array of (15,2). Is the problem with the values of M?

Comment: Hi there! Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and modify your example accordingly. This should make it easier for people to help you out. At present, your example doesn't work because you do not supply `M`.

Comment: I update it @sobek . should i provide values of M?

Comment: Yes that would be very helpful.

Comment: Updated @sobek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i get when i run

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


M = np.array([[12.647, 4.2439],
              [13.744, 8.9295],
              [13.93, 9.191],
              [16.223, 12.452],
              [16.475, 12.784],
              [16.535, 12.813],
              [16.774, 13.377],
              [16.949, 13.465],
              [17.295, 13.494],
              [17.329, 13.613],
              [18.183, 14.683],
              [19.055, 14.871],
              [19.098, 15.487],
              [21.798, 16.23],
              [22.241, 16.411]])

x1, y1 = np.meshgrid(M[:, 0], M[:, 1])
f = np.sqrt(x1 ** 2 + y1 ** 2)
plt.contour(x1, y1, f)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is this what you want? If not, please explain in detail what you would expect to see.

Comment: I didn't get this, I got a blank square.

Comment: Copy and paste the code i posted above. If you get something different, there's an issue with your python, numpy or matplotlib installation.

Comment: Got it, Thanks!